# PHP MySQLi numrows outputs 1 even if the value is higher or lower than 1

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have this PHP script, which outputs the variable inside the `lr` column:

```
$conx = mysqli_connect("value here", "value here", "value here", "value here");
$sql = "SELECT lr FROM locations";

if (mysqli_connect_errno($conx)){
    die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
        $query = mysqli_query($conx, $sql);
        $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        if ($numrows > 1) {
            echo "No locations found";
        } elseif ($numrows == '1') {
            echo "1 location found";
        } elseif ($numrows > 0) {
            echo $numrows." locations found";
        }
        // Free result set
        mysqli_free_result($query);

mysqli_close($conx);
```

Everything seems to work fine, but when it outputs the result it always outputs `1` even if the value is higher or lower than `1`
Anyone with a solution?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: The value inside the `lr` column, for example the value is `2` but still outputs `1 location found`

Comment: That's what `mysqli_num_rows()` does and has done its job. If the column is not empty, then it outputs `1 location found`. If you want to view the number `2` which is in the column, then you need to fetch the results.

Comment: Good catch @Wrikken That `==` eluded me.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: nah, deleted it, as you were right. `mysqli_num_rows` is not the way to get the value of the `lr` column ;)

Comment: So I should just use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` or `mysqli_fetch()`?

Comment: What with all these numbers being thrown around, it's a wee-bit hard to know exactly what the OP wants to achieve. @Wrikken - My original comment is what I took from posted code.

Comment: To (fetch/go through) echo out the results (if that's the goal) is to loop through your results, using a `foreach` or `while` @MarcusSchack-Abildskov

Comment: Yes, you would use those along with my above-said comment. @MarcusSchack-Abildskov

Comment: Ok, thanks guys. I will see if I can get it to work correctly

Comment: I posted a little something for you below. Check it out, see if that's what you'd like to get as a result. @MarcusSchack-Abildskov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, see if it suits your goal: (this is a very basic example)

```
$conx = mysqli_connect("value here", "value here", "value here", "value here");
$sql = "SELECT lr FROM locations";

if (mysqli_connect_errno($conx)){
    die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
$query = mysqli_query($conx, $sql);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);)
        {
            echo $row['lr']." ";
        }

mysqli_close($conx);
```

Comment: @MarcusSchack-Abildskov Great, am glad to hear it Marcus. Cheers, and you're welcome.